# Как построить логику выполнения этой задачи в SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть таблица с полем ‘Тариф’, есть таблица с таким же названием. [image: Таблица тариф]

Логика должна быть такая, пользователь выбирает срок эксплуатации и определенный риск ( ущерб, угон или кража доп.оборудования ) и после в поле ‘Тариф’ должно вставиться значение из таблицы ‘Тариф’ соответствующее выбранному полю и сроку эксплуатации. Как это организовать через SQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для более точного ответа нехватает структуры таблицы Тариф. А вообще такие задачи решаются с помощью join.

В начале вам необходимо сформировать выборку, в которой предстваленны все указанные вами поля и поле тариф. Однако для того, чтобы сформировать эту выборку не хватает информации, какое поле в таблице тариф соответствует какому-либо полю из указанной таблицы.

Из контекста складывается впечатление, что срок эксплуатации есть в обеих таблицах, в таком случае скрипт будет выглядеть приблизительно следующим образом:

```
select 
    a.*, 
    b.tariff
from table1 as a
join tariffTable as b
on a.lifetime = b.lifetime
and a.lifetime = <значение, указанное пользователем>
```